# Minecraft Fabric modding change class declaration in mixin

Tags: java, minecraft, mixins, minecraft-fabric

I am creating a Fabric mod for Minecraft and was trying to change a variable in the declaration of a class. I am new at modding with Fabric and I am not sure how to do this.

In the class `net.minecraft.network.packet.c2s.play.PlayerMoveC2SPacket` I wanted to change how the x, y, and z locations were declared.

```
protected final double x;
protected final double y;
protected final double z;
protected final float yaw;
protected final float pitch;
protected final boolean onGround;
protected final boolean changePosition;
protected final boolean changeLook;

protected PlayerMoveC2SPacket(double x, double y, double z, float yaw, float pitch, boolean onGround, boolean changePosition, boolean changeLook) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.yaw = yaw;
        this.pitch = pitch;
        this.onGround = onGround;
        this.changePosition = changePosition;
        this.changeLook = changeLook;
```

I want to change it to this:

```
this.x = (double) Math.round(x);
this.y = (double) Math.round(x);
this.z = (double) Math.round(x);
this.yaw = yaw;
this.pitch = pitch;
this.onGround = onGround;
this.changePosition = changePosition;
this.changeLook = changeLook;
```

I tried to use an `@Overwrite` but that gave an error. Is there any way to do this, or is it impossible?